# Application name has .app as suffix in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6

When I run my iPhone app on simulator it has app as suffix in the app name. I have entered only name of the app in Product Name in Build Settings and also in bundle display name and bundle name in info.plist.

For example, if app name was A.B.C. I have it as A.B.C.app in its name in simulator. The app was having correct name pre-iOS8 but it has started to happen in iOS8 with xcode6.

Comment: What happens if you reset the simulator, clean the Xcode project, and build again?

Comment: I have done that but it is still showing app as suffix in the app name

Comment: OK I see the bug now. If I give app name as A.B.C I see it A.B.C.app in the simulator and if I give the name A.B.C. I see it correct i.e, A.B.C

Comment: So the trailing `.` made the difference?

Comment: yes, looks a bug to me

Comment: Could be worth [filing a radar](http://radar.apple.com).

Answer (score 1):

As @pankaj mention in comment `"A.B.C."` remove an `.app` suffix. But is shows as `"A.B.C."` (with dot on end). I ended up with something like this `" A.B.C "` (with spaces on start and end on the name).

Comment: Also works with a single space at the end, e.g. `"A.B "`. XCode 7.